# Extraction of UDP data stream from pcap file

Tags: python, udp, wireshark, tshark

how can i get udp data stream (in ascii format) of all packets captured in pcap file into a text file using tshark.
I tried this

```
tshark -V -r /tmp/file_src.pcap > file_dst.txt
```

but how can i get only udp data stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tshark's -Y flag to specify a filter

```
tshark -V -r /tmp/file_src.pcap -Y udp > file_dst.txt
```